# appending string values

Tags: javascript

How do you pass parameters in onChange event?
I am appending the values to a string builder:

```
.append("onchange=\"abc(), xyz('").append(name).append(",").append(type).append("' )\">")
```

Comment: i am getting xyz('aaa,bbb') instead i need xyz('aaa','bbb')

Comment: What do you want to have here? Why not working with the string operator `+`? E.g. `'onchange="abc(), xyz(\'' + name + ',' + type + '\');"'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
.append("onchange=\"abc(), xyz('").append(name).append("','").append(type).append("' )\">")
```

?